# OMG Tokens locked in smart contract - onlyPayloadSize

Tags: solidity, contract-design, erc-20

My OMG Tokens are locked into a smart contract due to modifier - `onlyPayloadSize`

Line #93 - https://etherscan.io/address/0xd26114cd6EE289AccF82350c8d8487fedB8A0C07#code

I had stored dozens of ERC20 tokens on a smart contract and easily get them all back but Tx fails whenever try to get back OMG tokens so dug out their token contract and found `onlyPayloadSize` which is not usual in any other ERC20 token contracts.

Following is the piece of code to collect ERC20 tokens on my smart contract:

```
function CollectERC20(address tokenAddress) onlyAdmin public {
    token tokenFunctions = token(tokenAddress);
    uint256 tokenBal = tokenFunctions.balanceOf(address(this));
    tokenFunctions.transfer(msg.sender, tokenBal);
}
```

Comment: What version of solidity was your contract compiled with?

Comment: @RaghavSood ^0.4.24 - https://etherscan.io/address/0xea140f4bd06b564672d6e4453efe49994c833a69#code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is likely unrelated to payload size, and related to the fact that your token interface expects `transfer()` to return a `bool`. OMG is one of a handful of major token contracts that deviates from the standard, and does not return bool. This causes code compiled with recent versions of solidity to fail when interacting with such a buggy contract.

The byzantium hardfork introduces a new opcode, RETURNDATASIZE, which (as the name implies) stores the return data size for a call. It's mostly targetted towards variable array size returns. However, in your case, it expects a return of a bool, but gets nothing, which then leads to a revert.

Solidity 0.4.22+ default to byzantium compatible code.

I'm afraid there is no way to recover that OMG.

Comment: This means OMG is not compatible with `transfer` happening on smart contract?

Comment: They are accessible through other smart contracts, but you need a token interface that does not expect transfer to return bool. Essentially, you need two interfaces, one for regular tokens, and one for tokens with this bug

Comment: This is helpful for anyone coming here to solve an issue related to calling the transfer method on a broken ERC20 contract in your own contracts: https://web.archive.org/web/20191015055624/https://medium.com/coinmonks/missing-return-value-bug-at-least-130-tokens-affected-d67bf08521ca